# FileSystemWatcher Notification crash when no breakpoints

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

Okay, this is pretty weird.

I made an app that listens for changes inside a file, and then duplicate those changes to another file. Everything was working alright, I changed almost nothing, tried to rollback my changes but still no luck.

So here is the problem : I have a `FileSystemWatcher`, and a method that gets called on the "`Changed`" event. For some time now, I noticed that my app crashes when there's a change so I looked at my method and everything is just fine. In fact, it runs when I put a breakpoint inside it. But if I remove the breakpoint then it crashes, leaving no worrying errors (I think) in the output other than:

```
The thread 'vshost.NotifyLoad' (0xa84) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'vshost.LoadReference' (0x17e8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'TimeDataDuplicator.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\Tommy Bergeron\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\vs-projects\TimeDataDuplicator\TimeDataDuplicator\bin\Debug\TimeDataDuplicator.exe', Symbols loaded.
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
The program '[6240] TimeDataDuplicator.vshost.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[6240] TimeDataDuplicator.vshost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

It is very weird that everything runs fine when there's no breakpoint... I tried cleaning my solution and my project but nothing worked.

Any ideas? Has anyone ever stumbled upon this?

Thanks a lot!

---

Here's the watcher:

```
private void StartWatcher()
{
    FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

    // Répertoire
    watcher.Path = @"C:\Symcod_data";

    // Nom du fichier à "watcher"
    watcher.Filter = "FILE_MSG.OK";

    // Choix des événements à notifier
    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Size;

    // Assignation de méthode pour les événements choisies.
    watcher.Changed += FileHasChanged;

    // Début de l'observation
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    WriteLogMessage("TDD_WATCH_STARTED");
}
```

And here's the method that gets called:

```
void FileHasChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    // Lecture du fichier original
    using (StreamReader fileReader = new StreamReader(originalFile))
    {
        // On garde en mémoire le contenu du fichier dupliqué
        StreamReader duplicatedCheckReader = new StreamReader(duplicatedFile);
        string duplicatedCheckContent = duplicatedCheckReader.ReadToEnd();
        duplicatedCheckReader.Close();

        // Traitement du contenu du fichier original
        string line;
        string middleLineContent;   // Contiendra seulement le millieu de la ligne (sans les caractères spéciaux)
        while ((line = fileReader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            // On se sert seulement que le millieu de la ligne pour faire la recherche des doublons
            middleLineContent = line.Substring(line.IndexOf("-") + 1, 16);

            // Vérification des doublons, si le doublon n'est trouvé on écrit dans le fichier
            if (!Regex.IsMatch(duplicatedCheckContent, middleLineContent))
            {
                // Initialisation de l'écriture
                try
                {
                    using (StreamWriter fileWriter = new StreamWriter(duplicatedFile, true))
                    {
                        fileWriter.WriteLine(line);
                    }

                    WriteLogMessage("WriteLine_SUCCESS (" + line + ")");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    WriteLogMessage("WriteLine_FAIL [Exception: " + ex.InnerException + "] (" + line + ")");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code for the event and how you set up the FileSystemWatcher?

Comment: Which line causes the exception?

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth : There's no exception in the method itself, I can get the InnerException from it since it's coming from nowhere :\

Comment: Also, I read on Google, that those exceptions are "normal"

Comment: Also, does your code change the file when the change event is triggered? As this would trigger the event again which would then run your code and so on and so on until it crashes

Comment: Exceptions don't come from nowhere ;-)

Comment: @w69rdy: Unlikely. That would be an StackOverflowException

Comment: @Tom: Where does it read that those exceptions are normal?

Comment: @Daniel Exactly, which is what could be causing the crash

Comment: @Tom: Try to put a `Thread.Sleep(100)` at the very beginning of your event handler, before the `using`. Is it still crashing?

Comment: @w69rdy: Eh... He is getting an IOException, not a StackOverflowException...

Comment: What does the log report? Do you see any success\error messages?

Comment: @Daniel Ah ok, maybe not a StackOverflowException then, but perhaps a FileAccessDenied exception. See my answer below

Comment: The methods runs completely without hiccups only when I put a breakpoint anywhere in it... The file gets changed, etc. That's what I find weird, there's no exception in those methods at all.

Comment: @w69rdy: when there's no breakpoints, the method does not get called at all. :S

Comment: Hurm, with the sleep it is working fine... WTF?

Comment: Simple: The event is triggered before the file handle is completely released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the problem is one of your two StreamReaders or the StreamWriter. I assume you try to access a file that is still locked by some other process or even by your own process.

Try to put a try catch around the *complete* code of your event handler. This will show, that the exception is happening in your event handler and not someplace else.

Comment: Pretty clever! So could I for instance, put a try catch, and in the catch call a timer then recall the method, so when it fails it automatically retry?

Comment: Also, you were right: +  $exception {"The process cannot access the file 'C:\\Symcod_data\\FILE_MSG.OK' because it is being used by another process."} System.Exception {System.IO.IOException}
Hehe :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Tom: About your first comment: Yes, you could do this. Or you could try to open the file read only

Comment: I don't want to open it read only because there's another app reading the file with a time interval. I have one fear : If my app only reads the file but the other app is trying to read it at the same time : will it prevent the second app to read the file because I'm already reading it? (I don't think since I don't open it in read only but I just wanna be sure) Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: A file can be opened readonly as often as you want at the same time from several different processes.